# MVC 3 Connection String Confusion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

Using VS 2010, MVC 3, and SQL Express, I've been following the tutorials on ASP.net.  I'm also using EF code first. So far, my connection string has been:

```
<add name="MusicStoreEntities"
     connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=MusicStoreDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=true"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Which creates the db in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS
```

I now want to have the database reside in the App_Data folder.  So I created a new web application following a different tutorial, but this time I added a SQL database to it, and modified the connection string for the membership database by changing the database name.  I then used aspnet_regsql.exe to create the membership tables.  I then created POCO classes, a controller and added seed data.  Since the database already existed, it complained about not having an EdmMetadata table.  Upon researching that I realized my mistake and deleted the database.  Not to mention the DB will be dropped and created as the project is modified.  Running the project again gave me the error "Initial catalog not specified" so I modified the connection string.  Running the project again I get the error 'C:\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\App_Data\School.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.

A search of my hard drive reveals this database does not exist.  My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="SchoolContext"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=School;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|School.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What is making it think the DB exists?  What do I need to do to get code first to create the DB in the App_Data folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I ended up changing the database name in frustration, a search of my registry revealed multiple entries for school.mdf in the app_data directory.  Removing these solved the problem.